# How to move an Azure web app to container

Tags: docker, azure-devops

I have an Azure web app running. I would need to move this application to docker so I can flexibly move my apps to different cloud services.

I am not sure if a web app can directly be contained in a docker file or whether I need to move it to Azure containers and then a docker file.

Please help

Tried creating and spinning web apps and their respective database. Not sure the next steps to containerize or dockerize this

Answer (score 0):

If you only have one docker image you can stick with Azure Web App for Containers, otherwise you will need to go on Azure Container Service.

You can look at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47232013/difference-between-azure-container-service-and-web-app-for-containers) for a quick comparison.